# Is this the right way to pass state to Redux action?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm using map to get the IDs from the array of objects in the render.

My code:

```
class AppliedCandidates extends Component {

  render() {
    const {
      appliedjobs
    } = this.props
    const {
      joblists
    } = this.props {
      joblists && joblists.map(joblist => {
        this.props.getAppliedJobs(joblist.id)
      })
    }
    return ( <
      div > {
        appliedjobs && appliedjobs.map(appliedjob => {
          return <ol >
            <
            li > {
              appliedjob.jobid
            } < /li> <
            li > {
              appliedjob.candidatephoneno
            } < /li> <
            /ol>
        })
      } <
      /div> 
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log("state", state);
  return {
    joblists: state.getJobs.job,
    appliedjobs: state.getAppliedJobs.appliedjob
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getAppliedJobs: (joblists) => dispatch(getAppliedJobs(joblists))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppliedCandidates);
```

and in the following code which is in the Redux action.js, if I uncomment the array variable "appliedjobs" the process goes into an endless loop. If I comment it out, I only get the last value.

```
var appliedjobs = []

const getAppliedJobs = (joblists) => {
  return (dispatch, getState, {
    getFirebase,
    getFirestore
  }) => {
    const firestore = getFirestore();
    firestore.collection('Jobs').doc(joblists).collection('AppliedJobs').where("jobid", "==", joblists)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        if (querySnapshot.empty === true) {
          dispatch({
            type: 'GET_APPLIED_JOB_ERROR',
            joblists
          });

        } else {
          //appliedjobs =[] 
          querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc3) {
            appliedjobs.push({
              candidatephoneno: doc3.data().candidatephoneno,
              jobid: doc3.data().jobid,
            });
          });
          dispatch({
            type: 'GET_APPLIED_JOB',
            payload: appliedjobs
          });
        }
      })
  }
};
```

How to get the values?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't dispatch actions in your `render` function. If you need to populate your data by dispatching actions to the store, you should do it in a lifecycle method, in this case I think `componentDidUpdate` fits best.
from facebook's [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate):

> componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated. This is also a good place to do network requests as long as you compare the current props to previous props (e.g. a network request may not be necessary if the props have not changed).

Answer (score 1):

As Dor Shinar has said, don't call actions on the render function. Why? Because render function will be invoked every time any props/state is updated. So, if you call the action there, you'll keep re-rendering your page since you'll keep getting new updated props from the dispatched action.

I'm not sure about your action, since I never use firebase. But I guess it's some query calls.

```
class AppliedCandidates extends Component {
componentDidMount() {
  // here, the joblists props will get automatically updates from the dispatched redux action, dont mutate/change the props by yourself, change it via action.

  const { getAppliedJobs, joblists } = this.props;
  getAppliedJobs(joblists); // to be honest, why your action have the input of array and you put up id of individual array item? So I just put the entire joblists as the function parameter.

}

render() {
  const { appliedjobs } = this.props;

  if (appliedjobs.length === 0) {
    return null;
  }

  return ( // you can add more
    <ol>
      {appliedjobs.map(appliedjob => <li>{appliedjob.id}</li>)}
    </ol>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    joblists: state.getJobs.job,
    appliedjobs: state.getAppliedJobs.appliedjob
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getAppliedJobs : (joblists) => dispatch(getAppliedJobs(joblists))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AppliedCandidates);
```